# Why do colors in CSS/HTML start with #

Tags: html, css, colors, specifications, formats

I wonder why the format `#FFFFFF` was chosen? Why `#` is important and what it means?

I've searched some popular websites but they mostly deal with explaining how to parse a value to red, green and blue and none is explaining from where `#` came.

Comment: It's basic knowledges of HTML / CSS. Please read book.

Answer (score 2):

it helps the HTML parser to identify that it is a hexadecimal value not an ordinary string